# Assembly AT&T assignment, puts() buffer & stack

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, att, puts

So I have a task to write a library to a program but I'm stuck at a crucial early point, the teacher suggested using fgets(buf,nr,dest) but the fgets isn't until later to get the input and puts(buf) to print.

Don't mind the comments, it's in Swedish and I have written them for myself to understand what's supposed to happen and how.

So the call from the main program is:

```
    .global main
main:
    subq    $8,%rsp         #Gör plats för 8 bytes i 64 bit stacken
    movq    $headMsg,%rdi       #Stoppa in meddelandet $headmsg i stacken rdi
    call    putText         #Lägg texten från buf från dess position i utbufferten
    call    outImage        #Skriv ut strängen som ligger i utbufferten i terminalen
    call    inImage         #Läs in en textrad från tangentbordet till inbuffen för indata och nollställ aktuella pos i buffen
    movq    $5,count        #lägg in 5 bytes i count
```

So $headMsg which is filled with characters gets put in to the stack on %rdi and I can read it if I print it in the first function putText (that's not the purpose of that part) but when I go into outImage which is the second call I get "segmentation fault" so I'm guessing that the values that I'm trying to copy to my buffer gets flushed when returning from putText.
Would I need to save it to the part of the stack that doesn't flush or how would you proceed, I have tried some different combinations but I can't seem to print anything but segmentation error in the function OutImage?
And I'm asking here since I can't ask my professor because she doesn't have time to help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>          #Inkludera standard I/O

.data                   #Specifiera data
inbuff:         .space  64  #Inbuffert, reserverar 64 bytes i minnet (.space går att använda liknande som .skip)
utbuff:         .space  64  #Utbuffert, 64 bytes i minnet
buff:           .space  64  #Buffert, Samma
buffpos:        .quad   0   #Lagrar 64 bitar (.quad liknande .long fast 64 resp 32 bitar)
inpos:          .quad   0
utpos:          .quad   0
Slut:           .asciz  "slut\n"

.text                   #Innehåller programkod

.global inImage             #Gör funktionerna globala
.global getchar             #så att de kan anropas i Mprov
.global getInPos
.global setInPos
.global putChar
.global putText
.global getint
.global setOutPos
.global getOutPos
.global putInt
.global outImage
.global getText
.global getInt


Clearbuffer:
#movq   $buff,%eax
#movq   $0,%ebx

inImage:                
                    #läser in en ny textrad från tangentbordet till er inläsningsbuffert för indata och nollställer
                    #positionen till den aktuella bufferten. Andra inläsningsrutiner kommer sedan att jobba mot den här
                    #bufferten. Om positionen står vid buffertens slut när någon av de andra inläsningsrutinerna nedan
                    #anropas ska inimage anropas automatiskt (i den aktuella rutinen), så att det alltid finns data att
                    #arbeta med.
#movq   $inpos, $0          #Nollställ inpos
movq    $inbuff, %rdi           #Lägg i inbuff, där inbuff är en bit reserverat minne(register destination index)
movq    $5,%rsi             #Högst 5-1=4 tecken (NULL räknas ju också)(rsi=register source index)
movq    stdin, %rdx         #Från standard input stdin=$0 om ej def.(rax/rdx= return value)
call    fgets

getInt:                 #Returnerar ett heltal, tolkar en sträng som omvandlas till en int när positionen i bufferten
                    #påträffas(ett tecken som inte kan ingå i ett heltal.)  

getText:                #Överför n tecken från aktuell position, returnera antalet verkligt överförda tecken

getChar:                #Returnerar ett tecken och flyttar fram aktuell position ett steg

getInPos:               #Returnera aktuell buffertposition för inbufferten

setInPos:               #Sätt aktuell buffertposition för inbufferten till n. n måste dock ligga i intervallet [0,MAXPOS].
                    #Om n<0 sätt den till 0, om n>MAXPOS sätts den till MAXPOS.

outImage:               #Skriv ut strängen i utbufferten i terminalen. Om någon av nedanstående utdatarutiner når 
                    #buffertens slut så ska ett anrop till outimage göras automatiskt så att man får en tömd
                    #utbuffert att jobba mot.                   
movq    $utbuff, stdout 
call    puts

putInt:                 #lägg ut talet n som sträng i utbufferten från och med den aktuella positionen. 
                    #Glöm inte att uppdatera aktuell position.

putText:                #Lägg texten som finns i buf från och med den aktuella positionen i utbufferten.

#subq   $8, utbuff          #lägg in buf i utbufferten
popq    utbuff
call puts
ret
#movq   %rdi, utbuff
#addq   $1,$utpos           #Uppdatera aktuell position i utbuff

putChar:                #Lägg tecknet c i utbufferten och flytta fram aktuell position ett steg.
#rensa stackarna

#movb   8(%rbp), %bl            #Lägg in en 8 bitar i rbp lower
#movq   $utbuff,%rcx            #
#movq   $utpos,%rax         #uppdatera position(+1)(Inc)
getOutPos:              #Returnera aktuell buffertposition för utbufferten

setOutPos:              #Sätt aktuell buffertposition för utbufferten till n. 
                    #n måste dock ligga i intervallet[0,MAXPOS]. Om n<0 sätt den till 0, om n>MAXPOS sätts den till MAXPOS.
```

Thankful for all the help!

BR Rickard

Comment: You are not passing any argument to `puts`, hence the fault. You will need `movq    $inbuff, %rdi` to print the contents of `inbuff` that you have just read. Also remove the `popq    utbuff;
call puts` because at the current state of the code that makes no sense and will cause an additional fault.

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear, but I'm not on the inImage part yet.
I have just done what I could there to make it easier later on.
What I'm struggling with is the outImage part which should be containing $headMsg but instead I get Segmentation Fault.
I have recieved strict restrictions about using different functions for separate things.

Comment: What I said applies to `outImage`. You can of course use `$utbuff` too.

Comment: Okay, but to remove the popq utbuff also?
I thought that was to move what was stored the last at the stack and then updating the position of the stack?
The puts was mostly there to test and search for where things went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!
I guess I used the popq in the wrong way..
And also by adding the ret made the program work better.
I'll continue working on this and making a new post if I have another problem.

```
movq    $utbuff, stdout
call    puts
ret

putInt:                 #lägg ut talet n som sträng i utbufferten från och med den aktuella positionen. 
                    #Glöm inte att uppdatera aktuell position.

putText:                #Lägg texten som finns i buf från och med den aktuella positionen i utbufferten.

movq    %rdi, utbuff
ret
```